# Shouldn't this TFA question be re-opened so it can be answered

Tags: discussion

This question,
[Any canon precedents of Psychometry that Rey's visions are also Psychometry? [closed]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126853/when-rey-touches-lukes-light-saber-why-does-it-bring-back-memories)

> closed as primarily opinion-based by phantom42, Jason Baker, Jonah,
>   Mooz, Ward May 3 at 4:00
>
> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert
>   experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost
>   entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific
>   expertise. If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the
>   help center, please edit your question.

And a comment that it was,

> voting to close based on our future works policy

I was genuinely very interested in why this was happening (what I asked in the question) and spent a few days  searching through Wookieepedia, when I found a definitive canonical answer. I did not know that meta is where you post these questions I so I posted the answer inside the questions post. But for correct form. The answer should be in  answer format ,have the edit removed and reopened for others to comment etc?

EDIT:

---

I am going to post a full answer as to why I think Rey used Psychometry and also had some of her own memories mixed in.

The first scene is Rey being transported by her vision to the halls of Cloud City on Bespin, from the novel,

> she saw in the distance a section of the famed Cloud City. Two figures
>   were locked in combat, distant, distant.

So obviously Rey was not there and could not have known about how the halls  looked. This had to be due to Psychometry

In the vision we Luke’s hand touching R2D2. Rey could have possible seen this herself or used Psychometry, so it is inconclusive.

The next part is the Knights of Ren standing in the rain over the bodies of the slain Jedi. Rey could have also witnessed this herself or could be Psychometry, so inconclusive.

Then we see someone being killed by Kylo Ren. I don't know what this means or is indicating.

Then we see Rey as a child standing next to Unkar Plutt,crying and calling back whoever left her there. This is obviously a memory.

The last part is what seems to be a vision of the future, with Rey standing before Kylo in the snow. So this also being that Rey is seemingly looking into the future, cannot be Psychometry

Bottom line, she had no way of ever knowing what the halls of Cloud City on Bespin looked like and could only have gained that image from the Lightsaber. The other images that could have been from Psychometry do in fact hint that they were from Psychometry, due to her young age, but the first fact is clear evidence in my mind that she used it.

EDIT 2: 
Question title for original thread.

Answer (score 3):

I get your argument, but I lean to leave it closed (and voted as-such).

You found an ability that is a possible explanation in Wookieepedia, but you have not found or presented any proof that Rey has this ability.

Right now, you've got two canon facts, but are merely speculating that they are connected. That, to me, is more of a comment than an answer.

That said, if it's re-opened, I'm not going to argue it.

Comment: Psychometry is an ability linked to the force. Rey is gifted in the force. Rey touches an object and deducts information about people or events associated with that object solely by touching it. Could not be more clear to me.

Comment: See edited post.

Comment: @KyloRen - "Correlation is not causation." Just remove the name Rey from the title and ask for canon precedents for Psychometry, as they would relate to, say, that scene in TFA (with Rey in it).

Comment: @Mazura, what else explains her visions?

Comment: @KyloRen - Apparently this 'Psychometry' thing you found. Please see my suggested title for your post.

Comment: @Mazura, my bad, I see what you mean. Check new question title and see if that is acceptable?